# What's up with -ly-based: -based as a suffix on non-nouns

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, adverbs, suffixes

I have always thought that the English "-based" suffix (*plant-based diet*, *[English-based creole languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-based_creole_languages)*, etc.) worked only on nouns. Adjectives, e.g. "large-based" or "sweet-based", don't work (though *sweetener-based* does), and when hearing "walk-based" one immediately assumes the noun version of "walk" (a stroll), not the verb "to walk". So verbs don't work either, nor do adverbs: "sweetly-based" is not a thing.

Yet:

- "physically-based rendering" ([adobe.com](https://www.adobe.com/products/substance3d/discover/pbr.html), title of a [book](https://pbrt.org/) — its writing as "physically based rendering" without the dash notwithstanding)
- "physiologically-based modelling" ([fda.gov](https://www.fda.gov/about-fda/center-drug-evaluation-and-research-cder/program-physiologically-based-pharmacokinetic-and-pharmacodynamic-modeling-pbpk-program))

To me (a non-native speaker) these phrases sound simply wrong. Surely it should be "physics-based rendering" and "physiology-based modelling"?

Is this a new development? Or does this already occur in other settings?

Comment: -_based_ is not a suffix. It's a word and it appears in the compound adjective _plant-based_, short for _based on plants_. Compounds are very common, and frequently idiomatic. And this is an old development; compound words have been part of Germanic languages' hallmarks for millennia.

Comment: Re "these phrases sound simply wrong" - because you're not a native speaker, you can probably discount any such notions (maybe they're based on how such things work in *your* native language). I just ran off an NGram chart to see [what words occur most often before ***based ideas.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+based+ideas&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) I'm not surprised to see the **8** most common words are all adverbs (culturally, religiously, empirically, biologically, scientifically, racially). The first noun "research" comes in at number 9.

Comment: @tomseding. I believe your ear is good. Those phrases are prolix and pleonastic.  Their authors should be asked to explain the difference between **physical rendering** and **physically-based rendering**, **physiological modeling** and **physiologically-based modeling**.

Comment: @Tim Physical rendering would be rendering that is true to physics, whereas physics-based rendering would be rendering that is *based on*, i.e. derived from but not necessarily matching perfectly, physics. (In computer graphics, it would indeed be preposterous to claim rendering that is perfectly phisically accurate.) To me, "physically-based rendering" would be rendering that is based in a physical way, where I'm not sure what "based rendering" would even mean. But that is probably my non-nativeness sneaking in again.

Comment: *-based* in that particular domain is then a sort of *disclaimer* or *qualification*: "based in part on and not fully in accord with".  But there's no need for such disclaimer with **physical rendering** or **physiological modeling** since *rendering* and *modeling* have implicit in their meanings the notion of "a representation" or "a simulation" and representations and simulations are never the real thing. As you say, it would be "preposterous" to expect them to be, so there's really no need for the disclaimer.

Comment: You could equally use *physiologically-oriented* or *physiologically-directed* or *physiologically-focused* or a bunch of other participles. (I'm sure some of the delicately-constituted pedants here would object that such terms are ugly or sub-optimal, but they're perfectly grammatical and have their place.)

Comment: @StuartF Sure, but Xly-oriented means "oriented in an X way", and similarly for directed and focused. What does "based in a physiological way" mean? When X is a noun, "X-based" means "based on X"; "to base on" is a phrasal verb and "to base" is not really a thing, or at least not commonly. What do you see as the commonality between "-based" and "-oriented" etc.?

Comment: The use of 'words' like 'sweet-based', or indeed '-based' compounds is strictly a matter of taste.

Comment: @StuartF: It is not a delicate constitution that motivates attempts to remove slop from expository prose, especially when the text is itself attempting to be precise.

Answer (score 3):

Where appropriate, compound adjectives of the [adverb] + [past participle] form are quite common, though the device is by no means totally productive.

Roger Woodham writing at [BBC World Services: Learning English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv224.shtml) explains:

> **Compound adjectives**
>
> ...
>
> *adjective / adverb + past participle*
>
> Adjective or adverb plus past participle is one of the most common
> patterns for forming compound adjectives. Some common examples would
> include:
>
> *cold-blooded*              *kind-hearted*
>                    *old-fashioned*  
>                
>          *open-minded*            
> *brightly-lit*              
>          *deeply-rooted*          
>          *densely-populated*          
>          *well-behaved*
>
> - *Most animals are warm-blooded but all reptiles are cold-blooded.*
> - *He was a cold-blooded murderer and showed no emotion of any kind.*
> - *She lived in an old-fashioned house, but was kind-hearted and open-minded*.
> - *Nevertheless, she held deeply-rooted beliefs about the sanctity of marriage.*
> - *The dimly- / brightly-lit streets in our town encourage / discourage burglars.*
>
> Note that adverb / past participle combinations when they are used
> with a copular verb like *be* or *seem*, and come after the noun they
> modify, are not hyphenated:
>
> - *The streets in our town are dimly / brightly lit and encourage / discourage burglars.*

Some would dispute Woodham's classification of *brightly[-]lit* say as compounds, regarding many such pairs as adverb + ed-form [strong] collocates and dropping the hyphen ... but *newly-formed* and *fully-formed*, for instance, are certainly used with the hyphen by some (in prenominal usage).

However one classes the whole set in use, or individual cases, the premodification based on [adverb] + [past participle] is very well known. But as it's not totally productive [eg **coldly-blooded*; **kindly-hearted*], individual cases should be checked for clarity and currency. I'd say that the two examples given are acceptable, and that the hyphen helps construal with unfamiliar couplets.

It's interesting to see that sometimes the adjective + ed-form, and sometimes the adverb + ed-form, exists as the compound adjective. Sometimes there is a choice (*deep-rooted* / *deeply-rooted*; *full-grown* / *fully-grown*; *high-strung* [largely US] / the open compound *highly strung* [largely UK]). It's possible that there is more of a pull towards the adverb form where the participle exhibits more of a dynamic verbal than an adjectival flavour (so *kind-hearted* but *bravely[-]fought*).

Comment: A fully-grown man is a man that is grown fully; a brightly-lit street is a street that is lit brightly. This pattern does not hold for the adjective versions: cold-blooded is not blooded coldly, but instead "with cold blood"; to me that has little to do with the verb "to blood", with "-blooded" instead being related to the noun "blood". Is physiologically-based modelling, modelling that is based physiologically? What is based modelling, and how can it be done in a physiological manner? Or am I retrofitting rules to a non-productive more general construction?

Comment: I do believe the construction as I interpret it in my previous comment *is* productive: one can speak in a fumbling manner, and a fumblingly-spoken word is certainly a thing, despite me certainly never having heard "fumblingly-spoken" before.

Comment: Among the examples with alternatives can arguably be found counterexamples: a full-grown man is not 'a man who has grown full'; a highly-strung man is not a man who is strung/stretched highly. But the hypothesis '[It's possible that] there is more of a pull towards the adverb form where the participle exhibits more of a dynamic verbal ... flavour' is not 'counterexampled'.

Comment: ***Fumblingly-spoken, bravely-fought, densely-packed,...*** don't sound to me like the kind of collations I would hyphenate. I initially thought ***brightly-lit*** was much more "credible", but [even that is very much a minority orthography.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+brightly-lit%2Ca+brightly+lit&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Note that the chart there is for ***a** brightly[-]lit*, so it's only gonna match attributive adjectival contexts, not predicative *The room was **brightly lit***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps I should have stated, but I am strictly talking about attributive use anyway. :)

Comment: It's only really just dawned on me now that I think I understand the implications of John Lawler's comment ***-based** is not a suffix. It's a word...* If the word-pair can be rephrased as *It was **spoken fumblingly / fought bravely / packed densely / lit brightly*** the hyphen isn't needed. Hyphens only apply when we can't do the reversal (the forms *It's **blooded cold / hearted cold / minded open*** are nonsense).

Answer (score 2):

Cambridge Dictionary shows two main usages of “-based” used as a suffix. Both  refers to formation of  adjectives from nouns:

***[-based:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/based)***

> used to form adjectives showing the main place or area in which something or someone works, lives, or does business:
> *a Manchester-based company*

> used to form adjectives describing the main thing from which a particular substance or object is made:
> *This is a cream-based sauce.*

Comment: Maybe those two categories *are* the main ones - I've no idea. But I certainly wasn't trying to find evidence *against* the Cambridge position when I happened to search for [" * based ideas".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+based+ideas&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Where "ideas" was just the first word that came to mind, with no "ulterior motive". And I don't think *any* of the top ten words occurring in that asterisked position match either of Cambridge's categories, so it doesn't look like a very useful assertion to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think the adjective “based”,  as you are showing, and “-based” as a suffix are two different usages.

Comment: ...but I do note that the page ends with *See also  **competency-based, fee-based, knowledge-based, paper-based, screen-based.*** And they don't *actually* say the two categories you've reproduced are the ***main*** ones - by implication, they're just a couple of versions that people do in fact use, which can serve as *examples* for other versions.

Comment: I think if you think *the adjective “based”, as you are showing, and “-based” as a suffix are two different usages,* you're barking up the wrong tree! Whether the hyphen is explicitly included or not has nothing to do with anything. Real language is *spoken*, and you can't hear hyphens!

Comment: *Based* is the past tense and past participle of the verb *to base*

Comment: @StuartF I guess that is the heart of the trouble: what does *to base* mean? "Car-based" is "based on cars", "car-focused" is focused on cars. But "highly-focused" (attributively, e.g. "a highly-focused person") is very focused, but what is "a highly-based action"? Or does "based" not follow the same pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer helps OP, who already knows that "based" can be used to form adjectives from nouns. (He gives the examples "plant-based diet" and "English-based creole languages" in his first sentence.) He asks about using "based" with adverbs, and I don't see how this answer actually addresses that.

Answer (score 0):

To say that something which is **carbon-based** is *elementally-based* is not idiomatic; **element-based** would be the more abstract or general form. Similarly it would be **physics-based** rendering, not *physically-based*, just as a wooden house is **wood-framed** not "woodenly-framed".

The word *connected* to **-based** must be a noun, not an adverb.

If something is on a concrete foundation, we don't say that it is "concretely-based":  *a concretely-based shed.
If a price is based on the market, we don't say that it is "mercantilistically-based" but **market-based**. *The price of eggs is market-based.*

If a religion is based on Platonistic principles, we don't say that the religion is *platonistically-based*. We resort to an adjective and say that the religion is "platonistic". In the same way, we'd say that a rendering is *physical*, not "physically-based". If a model is based on the kinetics of physiology, we'd say that it was a *physiological model*, not that it was "a physiologically-based model". If we're talking about modeling, we'd say *physiological modeling* not "physiologically-based modeling". Just as the religion is not Platonism but Platonistic, that is to say, it is based on a certain subset of Platonic principles, the physical rendering is based on a certain subset of physical principles, and a physiological model is based on a certain subset of physiological principles.

Comparisons with words like **deeply-rooted** are inapt. To be **rooted** means to have roots that go down into the soil. There, how far the roots go down is an aspect of being rooted, which lends itself to **deeply-rooted**. Similarly, something can be **slow-cooked** as cooking takes time, and sometimes cooking something very slowly makes it more delectable. *It is the particular adjective that admits or does not admit an adverbial construction.*

Comment: Thank you, this chimes well with my feelings about this construction. However, your (and my) conclusions are at odds with the other two answers. I wonder if this is a difference between the two shores of the Atlantic.

Comment: I don't see my answer to be at odds with the answer given by @user66974